# center align a floated nav bar and dropdown from left to right

Tags: html, css, navbar

i want to center align whats in the nav bar( so that the img is the center of the nav bar. I know that i have float: left; but if i dont, the(left thing, right thing) will drop down to the bottom edge of the img. So what i want is to keep float left, but be able to display: inline-block, or something equal. I also want the dropdown bar for the (left thing) to start at the img's left side, and then build out to the right side.
 [**demo fiddle**](http://jsfiddle.net/7yrX7/114/)

**HTML**

```
  <div id="nav">
    <div id="container">
        <ul>
            <li>
               <a href="#"> Left thing </a>

                <ul>
                    <li><a href="#"><----- want it to go this way</a>
                    </li>
                    <li><a href="#">i want this to start under left thing</a>
                    </li>
                </ul>
            </li>
            <li>
                <img src="http://www.jonathanjeter.com/images/Square_200x200.png" style="height:70px" />
            </li>
            <li>
              <a href="#"> Right thing </a>

                <ul>
                    <li><a href="#">This starts right</a>
                    </li>
                    <li><a href="#">And this is right</a>
                    </li>
                </ul>
            </li>
        </ul>
    </div>
</div>
```

**CSS**

```
* {
    padding: 0;
    margin: 0;
}
#body {
    padding: 0;
    margin: 0;
    font-family: Arial;
    font-size: 17px;
}
#nav {
    background-color: 72776A;
    width: 100%;
    position:fixed;
    height:50px;
}
#nav ul {
    list-style-type: none;
    padding: 0;
    margin: 0;
    position: relative;
    display:block;
}
#nav ul li {
    float:left;
}
#container {
    text-align:;
}
#nav ul li:hover {
    background-color: #333;
}
#nav ul li a, visited {
    color: ACD661;
    display: block;
    padding: 15px;
    text-decoration: none;
}
#nav ul li:hover ul {
    display: block;
}
#nav ul ul {
    display: none;
    position:absolute;
    color: red;
    border: 1px solid black;
}
#nav ul ul li {
    display: block;
}
#nav ul ul li a:hover {
    color: #699;
}
```

Comment: It helps a lot if you indent your code. Right now it's hard to tell what's inside of what.

Answer (score 0):

replace

```
#container {
  width: 270px;
  margin: 0px auto;
}
```

Check [this](http://jsfiddle.net/7yrX7/115/) fiddle

Answer (score 0):

Before talk about solution let's talk about your CSS, i removed repeats for `margin:0, padding:0`, highlighted forgetted selectors or mistyping. You need to precise a `width` to your container `div` and add `margin-left` and `margin-right` auto to achieve what you want :

```
/* {
    padding: 0;
    margin: 0;
} not the best solution, everybody don't need this rule */

/* instead here a group of selectors */

body,
#nav ul {
    padding: 0;
    margin: 0;
}
/*#*/body { /* you mean just body right ? */
    font-family: Arial;
    font-size: 17px;
}

#nav {
    background-color: #72776A; /* you forgot # here */
    width: 100%;
    position:fixed;
    height:50px; /*it's smaller than your image*/
}
#nav ul {
    list-style-type: none;
    position: relative;
    /*display:block; don't need */
}

#nav li {
    float:left;
}
#container {
    /*text-align:; seems it's missing something here ? */
    margin: 0 auto;
    width: 300px;
}

#nav ul li:hover {
    background-color: #333;
}

#nav ul li a,
#nav ul li a:hover,
#nav ul li a:visited {/ { /* you mean a:visited ? */
    color: #ACD661; /* here again # forgot */
    display: block;
    padding: 15px;
    text-decoration: none;
}
#nav li:hover ul { /*ul don't need (i mean #nav ul li...) */
    display: block;
}
#nav ul ul {
    display: none;
    position:absolute;
    color: red;
    border: 1px solid black;
}
#nav li li { /* shorter then ul ul li */
    display: block;
}
#nav a li a:hover {
    color: #699;
}
```

You can see code [here](http://jsfiddle.net/7yrX7/118/)